# Gnuplot looping and divide column by previous column

Tags: gnuplot

I have a dataset which I am looping through plotting using the following script:

```
   do for [i=4:${numcols}:2] { 
      plot '${output}' using 0:i with lp title columnhead 
   }
```

How can I make it so that I am plotting the (i+1)th column divided by the 78th column, all divided by the ith column?

ie col(i+1)/(col(78) * col(i))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it ought to work. Are you getting an error?  The only problem I see is that "title columhead" is now ambiguous because you have referred to 3 separate columns in the plot.  Replace it with "title columnhead(i)"  or i+1 or whatever, giving

```
do for [i=1:NUMCOLS:2] {
    plot OUTPUT using 0:(column(i+1)/column(78)*column(i)) title columnhead(i+1)
}
```

Comment: @Ethan_Merritt Thanks. That works for me. I found the "column" construct about 30 seconds before your post, but the columnhead(i) was new.